# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null - Can't find answer

Tags: html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dob5K.png

This is the entire HTML that I have right now, and I'm not understanding why I'm getting an error here. I've looked up other versions of this on the site and none of the answers match my problem.

Comment: Put your second `script` tag at the bottom of your `body` element. Your JS is being run too soon and that element isn't present.

Comment: Post your code as code, not a as screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with this in a jsfiddle, and moving the img around with the arrow keys seemed to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/QsERY/

I'm not too sure why it doesn't work in your example, but try putting your script tags in the `<head>`?

(P.S. Please paste your code next time instead of linking to an image, it makes it much harder to answer your question)